# 32bit Python on Win7-64bit, import errors

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ipython

When I try to launch `ipython qtconsole` from anywhere except my Python install dir, I get import errors. It seems to only work if I RUN->cmd.exe; cd C:\Users\me\python\Python27; ipython qtconsole;.

Ive tried Batch files, but it still seems if I don't run it within the context of my install dir, it just doesnt work. Always ipython-script that seems to be complaining. Here is the output...(this was from inside ipython with CurrentWorkingDirectory as my Desktop)

```
In [2]: !ipython qtconsole
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\python\Python27\ipython-script.py", line 770, in <module
>
load_entry_point('ipython==0.12', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 402, in launch_new
_instance
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch_config_err
or
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 302, in initialize

  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch_config_err
or
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\core\application.py", line 325, in initialize
   File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py", line 297, in parse_comm
and_line
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch_config_err
or
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 413, in parse_command_l
ine
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 84, in catch_config_err
or
   File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\application.py", line 349, in initialize_subc
 ommand
   File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 40, in import_item
  File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\frontend\qt\console\qtconsoleapp.py", line 30, in <m
 odule>
   File "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin\lib\site-packages\ipy
 thon-0.12-py2.7.egg\IPython\external\qt.py", line 42, in <module>
 ImportError: Cannot import PySide >= 1.0.3 or PyQt4 >= 4.7
```

Like I said, it works perfectly fine from within my install dir, and I am 96% sure my ENV variables PATH,PYTHONPATH,PYTHONHOME are kosher. Ive gone from deleting them, to completely overloading them one directory at a time, with no change in results.

And I have made sure the Wow6432None Python entries exist (I tried not to pollute those).

Ipython is not the only module with errors like this (also with same solution), but this is definitely the most annoying (I can't launch qtconsole from Run Prompt!)

EDIT::I did dig up a start menu entry, and after changing the 'start in' property, I was able to launch qtconsole, but I still don't quite understand why this import is being performed relative to the current directory.

Comment: This path `c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin` does not exist on my computer. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it had to do with qtconsole dependencies living in locations not directly on my defined `PATH`, and I believe there were some conflicts in my modules search PATHS.

The easiest solution I found was to use the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

It has been a while since my original post, and several things have changed since then, but I believe the important factors were these:

-Be careful of 32bit python installed on 64bit windows.

-Utilize PYTHONPATH to include important sub-directories, such as '/install-dir/Lib' or any others.

If you still have trouble with your env variables, use absolute commands as a failsafe (wrap these up in a script that makes it easier to use),

```
C:\Users\johnny42\python\Python27\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\johnny42\python\Python27\ipython-script.py qtconsole
```

The above example should be on ONE LINE. Do not just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I have Python 32 bit in my 64 bit Windows OS. Even I have a similar error "c:\cpd-svn\branches\qt-4.8\win32-12-01\install\bin". I do not know where is it being set. Can you please share your findings as to where Python is getting this path from? And which path it should be updated with?

Comment: This path is not the concern, or the problem. The fact that you see it means that it is working. This path might come from eggs or processed .pth files. Even if I knew how (which I don't), you probably shouldn't need to change this path. The package that fails to import is the one you should be focused on (PyQT4 in my specific case). In my case, the problem was that some of the binary PyQT4 dependencies were in a separate directory, and I had to add that location to my PYTHONPATH explicitly.